# erros using contextInfo with NSAlertPanel and ARC to pass data

Tags: cocoa

the answer for this question is probably simple but currently I'm stumped and any help would be welcomed.

I have attached a contextual menu to a table view. One of the menu options is to delete the element in the tableview.  I'm using a NSAlert to pop a modal window to confirm deletion.  I'd like to pass along a value from the tableview to the alert selector so I have some reference to use for the delete.
here is the alert string:

```
    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:_window
        modalDelegate:self
        didEndSelector:@selector(deleteAlert:code:context:)
        contextInfo:s];
```

any time I try to pass an object as the contextInfo I get a warning.  If I try to pass NSInteger row (row from tableview) I get this compiler warning: warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to parameter of type 'void *'
If I try to pass a string in variable name form I get this:  error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'void *' is disallowed with ARC. I also tried a dictionary without any luck.

However if I pass a string like this: contextInfo:@"some info",I don't get any errors and I can actually see it in the selector. which of course is kinda useless for my needs.

So, how do I pass the table row information into the alert so I can use it in the delete selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass the row index, you can wrap it in an `NSNumber` instance:

```
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:_window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(deleteAlert:code:context:) contextInfo:(__bridge void *)[NSNumber numberWithInteger:row]];
```

Comment: thanks for your quick help but I still get the same error  error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'void *' is disallowed with ARC

        [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:_window
            modalDelegate:self
            didEndSelector:@selector(deleteAlert:code:context:)
            contextInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:row]];

Comment: I forgot the important part which is the __bridge cast.

Comment: thank you.  the __bridge cast works, but now I'm having an issue unwrapping the NSNumber back to an integer. The contextInfo is labeled targetRow.  This code fails with bad reciever type void.
`code`
    NSInteger affectedRow = [targetRow integerValue];
`code`

Now I want to get the row variable back out so I can use it in a look up on an array:
`code`
    [printerNames objectAtIndex:affectedRow]
`code`

thanks for your kind help.

Comment: You can get it out like this: `NSInteger row = [(__bridge NSNumber *)targetRow integerValue]`